# What should we do about questions that are written as announcements?

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across this question in the triage queue today:

[SASS undefined mixin errors : --watch on a folder responsible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610694/)

Since this is not really a question, I have flagged the question as "unclear what you're asking". This seems to be the path taken earlier with [this question/announcement about a cmd.exe parsing bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284131/cmd-exe-parsing-bug-leads-to-other-exploits)

What should we do to handle announcements of this sort, and how can we encourage users to write such posts in the question and answer format expected for SO?

Edit: The OP has responded to my comment by saying:

> So, it's still a question wrapped into a projection : "does this
>   explaination is the good one ?". If so, it can lead to point out
>   further SASS improvments.

Comment: This looks blatantly a case of treating SO like a personal blog. It's hard to admit it even after it was split into a question and an answer, because it seems to hide an overly broad question.

Comment: This person seems to have put a lot of effort into compiling the list of issues that the OP has seen in an attempt to provide an explanation to all of them in one fell swoop. However, that doesn't make it on topic for StackOverflow, at least not in the current format. The way it's written reads, just like the OP says, like an article. But from what I can see, it would be hard for a person with any of the issues mentioned in the question to be googling and happen upon this question because it is not set up in the expected question/answer format, so the question is not very useful.

Comment: 'We have to announce the imminent closure of this question.  We regret the incovenience caused and we offer either a full refund or rebooking on another website'.

Comment: Looks like he has edited the question to actually have question now.

Comment: Haha I thought this was going to be about announcements on meta.

Comment: I'm confused. The question seems to be basically of the form, "Why am I getting this error?" This is especially evident in the second half, where they present an error and then offer an unconfirmed guess. The earlier part appears to be an attempt to demonstrate research, something that most questions *sorely* lack. What am I missing? I'd much rather answer a question like this than most of the "gimme teh codez" crap I run across.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple enough: mark it as "unclear what you're asking" since it's unclear what's actually being *asked*.

There's nothing else to really do on that regard.  I've left a link to how one can actually self-answer questions on their own.  I wouldn't personally want to engage any further than what I already have since I feel reasonably confident that the point has been conveyed.

Comment: [Hey, Makoto, I don't think your answer was clear, maybe you should have spelled every step out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSczf.png)

Comment: Oh... huh. That flag was raised minutes *before* the question was reopened, i.e. while the question was closed. So I guess you should have spelled out that there's no need to flag a question for closure after it's been closed. (Yes, we get these types of flags from time to time - I still don't understand what goes through people's minds for them to think telling us a question was closed for the stated reason is a sensible, logical thing to do. They're not asking for the question to be reopened, just... telling us it's closed.)

Comment: I mean, I could've spelled it out, but Super Bowl, y'know... I do find it awkward that they decided to flag a closed question to be closed though...

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, a rebuttal to the comment by the original OP:

> So, it's still a question wrapped into a projection : "does this explanation is the good one ?". If so, it can lead to point out further SASS improvements.

... would be that *"is this a good explanation"* is an "Asks for opinion" question.  This is not to say that that the question cannot or should not be reworded to be fact based.

(And the rebuttal may be redundant now anyway ...)